# Convergence of function with matrix as input

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, algebraic-graph-theory

Given a binary symmetric matrix $A$, an integer threshold $K$, 
function $$f(A)=A^2 \geq K$$ the $\geq$ is element-wise, so we get another binary matrix after applying  $\ f$.

I want to show whether the convergence of the following holds.
$$f \circ f \circ ... \circ f(A)$$

I tried all the possibilities where size of $A$ under $6$, they will all converge after applying $\ f$ twice.

I see the difficulty lies in the input which is a matrix. Any ideas about where to start to solve this problem?

Comment: Your definition of $f$ is really not clear... is it $f(A)=A^2$ or $f(A)_{i,j} =1$ if $(A^2)_{i,j}\geq K$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The definition is the latter. $f(A)_{i,j}=1$ if  $(A^2)_{i,j} \geq K$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Ok and $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ or $A\in\Bbb Z_2^{n\times n}$?

Comment: $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$